# SMS syncable software for computer/phone? - Like iMEssage

Tags: phone

I'm looking for software/app/something that allows me to use SMS on the computer. It would be awesome if it worked like iMessage and Mac, where you can have your convo and it will sync with the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend [MySMS](http://www.mysms.com/). I love that it also allows you to text from non-phone devices like Tablets.